# Is it possible to create a connection string for an Azure function programmatically?

Tags: azure, powershell, connection, azure-functions, command-line-interface

I wonder if anybody knows how to add a connection string to an Azure function using a Powershell script? Perhaps something similar to this:

az functionapp config appsettings set --name FunctionName --resource-group MyResourceGroup --settings "ConnectionStrings=connection_value_here"

This command does create an application setting. I haven't been able to find a similar for connections.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found a simpler solution:

`az webapp config connection-string set -g "$ResourceGroup" -n "$FunctionAppName" -t custom --settings SchedulerServiceBusConnection="$FunctionConnectionString"`

Just need to replace the values in quotes.

Comment: em, you're aksing for a `powershell script` in your question, but it's`azure cli` in your answer. You'd better write a clear question:).